# Does not contain _id or shard key for pattern {_id:hashed}

Tags: mongodb

```
db.books.update({bookId:"123461"},{$set:{"bookPrice":"6.23"}})
```

I get the error:

```
   update { q: { bookId: "123461" }, u: { $set: { bookPrice: "6.23" } }, multi: false, upsert: false } does not contain _id or shard key for pattern { _id: "hashed" }
```

But when I use below it works.

```
 db.books.update({_id:ObjectId("54b88167498ec382221a82c2")},{$set:     {"bookPrice":"6.23"}})
```

Why doesn't it work with the bookId

Comment: Are you using a sharded cluster or is the "shard key" message just part of the error message that you triggered?

Comment: I am using a sharded cluster. Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason is because you are on a sharded cluster and you are identifying the document you wish to update with an index that is neither unique nor is it the shard key however you have specified that you only want to update 1 document. (`multi: false`)

Consider that when you make a query that does not include the shard key, mongodb has to scatter the query to ALL of the shards because there is no way for `mongos` to figure out which shard the document might be on.

So if `mongos` were to broadcast your query to all of the shards, two or more of them may find a document that matches your query and they would both update the document they found. This would violate your `{multi: false}`.

Now perhaps ***you*** know that `bookId` is a unique identifier, but your mongodb cluster does not. Is there any chance that you could replace `bookId` with the `_id`? That is, could you change the document so that instead of having a `bookId` field, it has `_id: "123461"`? Or if you know `bookId` is unique you could just set `multi: true`. Though it will not be an efficient operation since the command will have to be sent to all of the shards even though the document is only in one of them.